# Got error : System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Parameter ?_1 has no default value.'

Tags: c#

i try to do a Insert query using following code, but it is not work..i got error called :

> System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException: 'Parameter ?_1 has no default value.'

```
private void BtnQuantity_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    con.Open();
    string addproducttocart = "INSERT INTO tbl_invoice_item ([Invoice_id], [BarcodeID], [ProductName], [Quantity], [EachPrice], [TotalPrice]) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
    cmd = new OleDbCommand(addproducttocart, con);

    // Add parameters in the correct order based on the SQL query
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", InvoiceID);       
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", ItemID);         
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", ProName);         
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", txtQuantity.Text); 
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", ItemPrice);       
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", Convert.ToDecimal(ItemPrice.ToString().Remove(0, 3)) *  Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Text)); 

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    con.Close();
    this.Close();
}
```

Comment: See the marked duplicate: `You need to pass DBNull.Value instead to pass a semantic null.`